# How do I use updatable displays on colab?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, google-colaboratory

On the Jupyter Notebook I can create named outputs that are able to be updated like this:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display
import time

def progress(value, max=100):
    return HTML("""
        <progress
            value='{value}'
            max='{max}',
            style='width: 100%'
        >
            {value}
        </progress>
    """.format(value=value, max=max))

out = display(progress(0, 100), display_id=True)
for ii in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.02)
    out.update(progress(ii, 100))
```

[image: progress bar]

Whereas in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com) it doesn't update the progress bar.

[image: colab no updatey]

How do you do this in colab?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Good news! This [now works in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1I2o3Ie34vJ3G4M6eE54-OyrmzJNBwhOp). :)

(Previously, we didn't support `update_display_data` messages.)

Pasting the code for anyone with sharing issues:

```py
from IPython.display import HTML, display
import time

def progress(value, max=100):
    return HTML("""
        <progress
            value='{value}'
            max='{max}',
            style='width: 100%'
        >
            {value}
        </progress>
    """.format(value=value, max=max))

out = display(progress(0, 100), display_id=True)
for ii in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.02)
    out.update(progress(ii, 100))
```

Comment: please link to bug report

Comment: do you know if similar functionality exists in R ? I'm using Colab with R chunk.